# Oracle 12c - Insert values in a table using values from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table (`TABLEA`) like so:

```
type_id  level
1        7
2        4
3        2
4        5
```

And another table (`TABLEB`) like so:

```
seq_id type_id  name     order level
1      1        display  1     7
2      1        header   2     
3      1        detail   3     
4      2        display  1     4
5      2        header   2     
6      2        detail   3
```

`TABLEB.TYPE_ID` is FK to `TABLEA.TYPE_ID`. Currently I am entering the data in `TABLEB` manually.

I have 2 new rows in `TABLEA`.. type_id 3 and 4.

How can I populate data which do not exist in `TABLEB` automatically using `TABLEA`? I would like all columns in `TABLEB` to be inserted automatically.

So, as you can see:

- `SEQ_ID` will be sequential
- When `ORDER` value is 1, `NAME` value will be "display", and `LEVEL` will be 7
- When `ORDER` value is 2, `NAME` value will be "header"
- When `ORDER` value is 3, `NAME` value will be "detail"

I am expecting after the insert:

```
seq_id type_id  name     order level
1      1        display  1     7
2      1        header   2     
3      1        detail   3     
4      2        display  1     4
5      2        header   2     
6      2        detail   3     
7      3        display  1     2
8      3        header   2     
9      3        detail   3     
10     4        display  1     5
11     4        header   2
12     4        detail   3
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. Have your application code populate both tables, i.e.: INSERTs the appropriate records into to both tables.
2. (Sounds like you're leaning to) Have Oracle do the work behind the scenes, i.e.: Oracle does the INSERTs in `TABLEB` for you.  The way to do this is by creating a TRIGGER on `TABLEA`.  Here's an example that might get you started:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13356277/1680777

Some people will tell you that TRIGGERs might make debugging difficult because part of your logic is in the database. There's some validity to that criticism. I won't say always/never use triggers. Use them where they make sense: where the value they provide outweighs their complexity.

Answer (score 0):

So this can be done in pure SQL: INSERT ALL which allows us to issue multiple inserts in the same statement.

```
insert all
    into tableb (seq_id, type_id, name, order_id, level_id) 
        values(tableb_id_seq.nextval, type_id, 'display', 1, level_id)
    into tableb (seq_id, type_id, name, order_id) 
        values(tableb_id_seq.nextval+1, type_id, 'header', 2)
    into tableb (seq_id, type_id, name, order_id) 
        values(tableb_id_seq.nextval+2, type_id, 'detail', 3)
select a.type_id, a.level_id from tablea a
minus
select b.type_id, b.level_id from tableb b
/
```

The manipulation of the sequence is a bit funny: it is required because every call to NEXTVAL returns the same value in one statement.  Obviously in order to make this work, the sequence needs to increment by three:

```
create sequence tableb_id_seq increment by 3;
```

This might be enough to rule out such an approach approach.  As an alternative you could use (SEQ_ID, ORDER_ID) as a compound primary key but that's not nice either.

---

By the way, ORDER and LEVEL are keywords: you can't use them as column names.